# Fastest jQuery autoellipsis plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery autoellipsis plugin. (autoellipsis plugins will add `...` at the end of a multiline text.)

I know these plugins: [autoellipsis](http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/) and [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/). but both working slowly in my jQuery Mobile project.

What is the fastest jQuery autoellipsis plugin?

EDIT: I have to call autoellipsis plugin on window resize event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This JsPerf (http://jsperf.com/truncate-vs-dotdotdot/4) compares the following truncating/ellipsis plugins:

- jquery dotdotdot 1.6.16
- jquery truncate 1.4
- autoellipsis 1.0.10
- truncate.js v0.1.0
- trunk8 v1.3.1

Those plugins are linked from the jsPerf. According to the results, the truncate.js out performs the rest.

Comment: Actually, seems that truncate.js needs to be told how many lines do we need. If we want to choose an automatic one, then jquery truncate outperforms the rest.

Answer (score 4):

[Trunk8](https://github.com/rviscomi/trunk8) is a great bundle for this.

Comment: It needs to tell how many lines it should show, but I don't know it. I want to show as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

what about [AutoEllipsis.jquery](https://github.com/SmartMedia/AutoEllipsis) ?

https://github.com/SmartMedia/AutoEllipsis/blob/master/autoellipsis.min.jquery.js **1.292 kb**

and here's a live example for using it http://jsfiddle.net/abdullahdiaa/s6WB5/

Comment: This is just a single line, but I want multiline autoellipsis

Comment: you can simply use "multiline" option , check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/abdullahdiaa/s6WB5/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is one that I rolled a while back, it supports multiple lines etc, I did have some "big" ideas for it but so far this has been useful enough as it is:

https://github.com/rmorse/AutoEllipsis